# Not able to fetch user email via facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using below:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'my-app-id',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.7'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

and trying to get email info as below:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function (response) {
     console.log(response.name + ' --- '+response.email);
});
```

The output is : Nitesh Kumar --- undefined

How to get email of user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask for the email permission in the login process:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user just authorized your app

    }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

Btw, this would be correct (including state oft the art ES6 arrow functions too):

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, (response) => {
     console.log(response.name + ' --- ' + response.email);
});
```

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/